# Model View Remote Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, remote-access

I am doing a remote validation using Remote attribute in my MVC model, please find the code below:

```
[Required]
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsEmailExist", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "The Email Already Exists")]
```

In the controller action method I use the user input of email as a parameter and check with the db, please find the code below:

```
public JsonResult IsEmailExist(string emailAddress)
{
    using  (var db = new YouTubeNZ())                                                
    { 
        var isExist = !db.Users.Any(X => X.EmailAddress == emailAddress);                                         
        return Json(isExist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                                 
    }
}
```

But during run time the parameter in the action method is "Null" when the value should be the user input email address and it is not getting validated for existing email.

Comment: What is the name attribute of your input field for email?

Comment: Show the property you apply this to - it needs to be `public string emailaddress`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you decorate your action method with `HttpPost` attr, and your property name matches the method parameter (i.e: `EmailAddress`):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsEmailExist(string emailAddress)
{
    using  (var db = new YouTubeNZ())                                                
    { 
        var isExist = !db.Users.Any(X => X.EmailAddress == emailAddress);                                         
        return Json(isExist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the following.

Your model property should be like

```
[Required]
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsEmailExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "The Email Already Exists")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Also change your AccountsController action method to

```
public ActionResult IsEmailExist(string emailAddress)
{
    using  (var db = new YouTubeNZ())                                                
    { 
        bool isExist = !db.Users.Any(X => X.EmailAddress == emailAddress);                                         
        return Json(isExist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                                                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Model should be like this

[Required]
[Remote("IsEmailExist","Account",ErrorMessage="This Email is already exists")]
public string EmailAddress{get;set;}

And Controller should be like this

public JsonResult IsEmailExist(string emailAddress)
{
    return Json(isExist(emailAddress),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private bool isExist(string emailAddress)
{
     using  (var db = new YouTubeNZ())                                                
     { 
        return  !db.Users.Any(X => X.EmailAddress == emailAddress); 
     }
}
```